# AccessibilityService restarting on boot

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

Once an Accessibility Service is connected by the user, is it restarted automatically on boot/reboot? This seems to be the case on an app I'm modifying. Just want to be sure after I couldn't find any info in the official docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  If a user is relying on an assistive technology to use their device, they shouldn't have to start it up every time.  Once it's on, it's on for good, unless it is intentionally shut off.